# Converting data type into query string

Tags: haskell

I'm building an API client for one service and the main reason to use that over raw API is to present all the nice types for the user.

One type I made is for optional query parameters which will be different for each endpoint (instead of forcing the user to provide a list of tuples of strings):

```
data ListDatasetsParams = ListDatasetsParams {
    offset :: Maybe Int,
    limit :: Maybe Int,
    desc :: Maybe Bool,
    unnamed :: Maybe Bool
}
```

Now I would like to convert this type into a Query which has the signature

```
type Query = [QueryItem]
type QueryItem = (ByteString, Maybe ByteString)
```

I didn't really find a way to do it at least a bit generic. The only way I got it working is pure hardcode where I check every param and manually add a correct string.

Can I do better? Or is there any other more idiomatic way to do this in Haskell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [generics](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC.Generics):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures, DeriveGeneric, FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances, TypeOperators #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import Data.String

type Query = [QueryItem]
type QueryItem = (ByteString, Maybe ByteString)

class ToByteString a where
    toByteString :: a -> ByteString
    default toByteString :: Show a => a -> ByteString
    toByteString = fromString . show

instance ToByteString Int
instance ToByteString Bool
instance ToByteString [Char] where
    toByteString = fromString

class GToQuery f where
    gToQuery :: f a -> Query

instance (GToQuery a, GToQuery b) => GToQuery (a :*: b) where
    gToQuery (a :*: b) = gToQuery a ++ gToQuery b

instance GToQuery a => GToQuery (M1 D c a) where
    gToQuery (M1 x) = gToQuery x

instance GToQuery a => GToQuery (M1 C c a) where
    gToQuery (M1 x) = gToQuery x

instance (Selector c, ToByteString a) => GToQuery (M1 S c (K1 i (Maybe a))) where
    gToQuery s@(M1 (K1 x)) = [(toByteString (selName s), fmap toByteString x)]

class ToQuery a where
    toQuery :: a -> Query
    default toQuery :: (Generic a, GToQuery (Rep a)) => a -> Query
    toQuery = gToQuery . from

data ListDatasetsParams = ListDatasetsParams {
    offset :: Maybe Int,
    limit :: Maybe Int,
    desc :: Maybe Bool,
    unnamed :: Maybe Bool
} deriving(Generic)

instance ToQuery ListDatasetsParams
```

It works like this:

```
*Main> toQuery (ListDatasetsParams (Just 1) Nothing (Just True) Nothing )
[("offset",Just "1"),("limit",Nothing),("desc",Just "True"),("unnamed",Nothing)]
*Main>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it will take me some time to fully understand it :)